# how to scan text from camera and return it into TextView?

Tags: android, android-activity

this is my first app
i want to create a simple app witch scan phone number from camera to save it into the mobile

how to scan text from camera ?

am i need API from another apps or not?

thanks

Comment: Doing OCR as your first app probably isn't going to be a "simple" project.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need library for text recognition, you can google optical character recognition, there are libraries for every language.